# Button in full-width, Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my HTML

```
<div id="formSuscription">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="button" class="form-control" value="Submit">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <center>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="Submit"> DON'T SHOW AGAIN
                </label>
            </div>
        </center>
    </form>
</div>
```

image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpa7rybvpngf19z/ohnails.png
I can't post image, due to my reputation

How can I make for the button is full width?

I tried with:

```
style: display: block; width: 100%;
```

and

```
class btn-block
```

and

```
<div class="form-group btn-group-justified">
<input class="form-control btn-block" type="button" style="display: block; width: 100%;" value="Submit">
</div>
```

but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can override current `css` by adding `id="submit"` to the `<button>` tag and use `css` to change it's width.

Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/b64yf2jm/2/

**You can do it statically :**

edit this:

`<input id="submit" type="button" class="form-control" value="Submit">`

use css:

```
#submit{
   width:180px; // <-- Your width value
}
```

**Or use `css` dynamically via `jQuery`:**

Here  what we do is assigning the `#submit` button `width` with `witdh` of the other fields on the form. ( I added `+8` to compensate padding or margins, just tweak it a bit )

jQuery:

```
$('#submit').css('width', $('.form-control').width()+8);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap shouldnt this work?

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Block level button</button>
```

Creates a button the full width of its container.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes

Phil